# create new column by filtering and using a reference table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue when creating a new data column based on conditions of a reference table. I want to loop through the 'Total Bags Packed' column and multiply it by the bag weight found in the bagwt dataframe. What ends up happening is I get a list of series for each row and I cannot convert this to a column of floats after. Is there a better way to go about this? code is below:

[Total Bags Packed example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Zg1.png)

[bagwt example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja5MD.png)

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
bagwt=pd.DataFrame()
df['Total Bags Packed'] = [2220,3320,2400,18]
df['Bag Product Code'] = ['20G.428', '76Q.435', '76Q.435', '76Q.S14']
bagwt['Bag Type'] = ['197','207','209','211','367','417','428','430','431','435','467','750','431L','S04','S12','S13','S14','S16','S25','S26','S28','S75','445']
bagwt['Wt'] = [50,2000,1800,1500,55,1200,55,55,55,50,1100,1650,55,55,2645,1300,1400,1650,2250,2600,700,750,50]

lbs = []

#calculate total lbs from bagwt and packaging df and add to the total lbs column

for i in df.index:
        lbs.insert(i,pd.to_numeric(df['Total Bags Packed'][i] * bagwt[bagwt['Bag Type'] == df['Bag Product Code'][i][4:7]].iloc[:,1], errors='coerce'))

df['Total Lbs'] = lbs

print(df['Total Lbs'])
0       6    122100.0
Name: Wt, dtype: float64
1       9    166000.0 
Name: Wt, dtype: float64
2       9    120000.0
Name: Wt, dtype: float64
3       16    25200.0
Name: Wt, dtype: float64
4        16    2800.0
Name: Wt, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

First combine the two dataframes and then perform the calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

# need to split 'Bag Product Code'
df[['Bag Code','Bag Type']] = df['Bag Product Code'].str.split('.',expand=True)

# now merge using 'Bag Type'
df = df.merge(bagwt, on=['Bag Type'], how='left')

# calculate
df['Total Lbs'] = df['Total Bags Packed'] * df['Wt']

​# result
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys'))

      Total Bags Packed  Bag Product Code      Total Lbs  Bag Code    Bag Type      Wt
--  -------------------  ------------------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----
 0                 2220  20G.428                  122100  20G         428           55
 1                 3320  76Q.435                  166000  76Q         435           50
 2                 2400  76Q.435                  120000  76Q         435           50
 3                   18  76Q.S14                   25200  76Q         S14         1400
```

Comment: Thank you! That is much better!